# EventHub Azure Function triggers correctly but EventData.Body is 0 bytes

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am writing an EventHub publisher (Console app) and an C# Azure Function that will work as a consumer. when I run the client, I can see the Function getting triggered, but it receives 0 bytes in`eventData.Body`. Can anyone help me here? I have seen some other similar questions about empty events received in Az Function. this is differnt, because trigger is fired everytime I send a batch of 10, but somehow the data is eaten up

My function code is

```
    [FunctionName("EventHubTrigger1")]
    public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("confighub", Connection = "EventHubName")] EventData[] events, ILogger log)
    {
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

        foreach (EventData eventData in events)
        {
            try
            {
                //eventData.Body is System.ReadOnlyMemory<Byte>[0] instead of what the sender is sending
                string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.Body.ToArray());

                
                log.LogInformation($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {messageBody}");
                await Task.Yield();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               
                exceptions.Add(e);
            }
        }

       
        if (exceptions.Count > 1)
            throw new AggregateException(exceptions);

        if (exceptions.Count == 1)
            throw exceptions.Single();
    }
```

the publisher is also simple and during debugging I can see that the `EventData.Body` is `System.ReadOnlyMemory<Byte>[456]`

```
private async Task SendToHub(IEnumerable<IDomain> users)
    {
        await using (var producerClient = new EventHubProducerClient(_eventHubConnectionString, _eventHubName))
        {
            try
            {
                CreateBatchOptions options = new CreateBatchOptions();
                
                options.PartitionKey = "user";
                using EventDataBatch eventBatch = await producerClient.CreateBatchAsync(options);

                foreach (var user in users)
                {
                    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(user);
                    
                    eventBatch.TryAdd(new Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)));
                }
                //During Debugging I can see that the Body is 456 bytes
                await producerClient.SendAsync(eventBatch);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the reason for using two different versions of EventHub library - version 5 used by the sender, version 4 by your Az function receiver.

**Just take into account that sender sends *Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.EventData* when the receiver gets *Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.EventData*.**

See for details [Guide for migrating to Azure.Messaging.EventHubs from Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/MigrationGuide.md).

**Try to switch to version 4 on the sender side, or downgrade the Function to use  Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs (**[code ref](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/MigrationGuide.md#migrating-code-from-eventhubclient-to-eventhubproducerclient-for-publishing-events-with-partition-key)):

```
var connectionString = "<< CONNECTION STRING FOR THE EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE >>";
var eventHubName = "<< NAME OF THE EVENT HUB >>";

var connectionStringBuilder = new EventHubsConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString){ EntityPath = eventHubName }; 
var eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());

try
{
    EventData eventData = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("First"));
    await eventHubClient.SendAsync(eventData, "my-partition-key");
}
finally
{
    await eventHubClient.CloseAsync();
}
```

Comment: I am using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs 5.2 on both the sides. there is no 4.0 for it on Azure.Messaging.EventHubs. Are you suggesting I need to go to the older library Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs on sender side?

Comment: I would downgrade the server-side lib just for testing.

Comment: your answer gave me the idea of sending just the plain string, instead of my json. that started throwing error on my Az Function saying that I need to change my EventData[] to string[]. when i did that, I got the "first message" in my logs. I then sent my json in eventData and received as string, and that worked!!! Thanks for helping me get to the answer

Comment: Versions 4 (`Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs`) and 5 (`Azure.Messaging.EventHubs`) are compatible; events published by one version can be consumed by the other.  We recommend using `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs` for development.   It's also worth noting that the Azure Function bindings are in the process of being upgraded to use `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs` as well.

Comment: I am using `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs`.  Surprisingly, I created another Az Function in VS Code and it worked without changing to string[]!! The code I posted yesterday was created using VS 2019. I am guessing there is something in the tooling that caused EventData.Body being 0 bytes for the one I was using yesterday. I swapped string[] back to EventData on my old project and ran it from VS Code and still the same error
Whereas the new project works like a charm. Will try and figure the difference between the projects and post and update if I find it.

Comment: the comment about Azure function binding is in the process of being updated helped understand the difference. I removed nuget reference to Azure.Messaging.EventHubs